# Move files into a folder based on only part of their name

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, script, batch-file

I have a bunch of files that I am trying to organize into folders based on the first 11 characters (Ex. `X-01234-567`) and some of the files have description after these numbers that help to identify what they are.
I have been able to make folders that only have these 11 characters and then move all files that start with the corresponding 11 characters into those folders.

The issue I'm having is that there already are a bunch of folders that have more than just those 11 characters (Ex. `X-09902-024 Adapter, 0.38 NPT`) etc.

I want the batch file to look for folders that already have the same first 11 characters as the part, and then move the part into that folder if they match, otherwise if there isn't a folder, then to create one. Attached are screenshots of the different ways I've tried it. I'm assuming it's something really simple, but I can't figure out the syntax.

I didn't know I couldn't add in images yet, so here are the copies of the two different batch files that I tried. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "basename=."
for /F "tokens=1* delims=." %%a in ('dir /B /A-D ^| sort /R') do (
   set "filename=%%a"
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   for /F "delims=" %%c in ("!basename!") do if "!filename:%%c=!" equ "!filename!" (
      set "basename=!filename:~0,11!"
      if not exist "!filename:~0,11!" md "!basename!"
   )
   move "!filename!.%%b" "!basename!"
   for /F "delims=" %%c in ("!basename!") do (
      endlocal
      set "basename=%%c
   )
)
```

The second one I tried is here:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'Dir /b *.dwg *.jpg *.pdf *.slddrw *.sldprt *.sldasm *.STEP^|findstr "^[X]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]" '
) do call :subr "%%F"
exit /b

:subr
set "file=%~n1"
set "fold=%file:~0,11%\"
if not exist "%fold%*" md "%fold%"
move %1 "%fold%"
```

[image: Image showing script working if folder was created by it]

The image I attached is showing how the files will go into the folder if it was created by the script, but there was a folder with the same name except with more characters, and it left it empty. Please let me know if you need me to clarify anything!

EDIT:

I used and modified LotPings script to get what I was looking for. A copy of it is below for reference.

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "basedir=F:\Kits Fixed\Test"

PushD "%baseDir%" || (echo couldn't locate baseDir & pause & exit /B 1)

:: iterate all dirs and move files with same prefix to dir
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir /B /AD ^| sort /R') do ( 
      set "file=%%A"
      set "folder=!file:~0,11!"
   Move "!folder!"*.* "%%A"

)

:: there shouldn't be any files left with matching dir

for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B *.dwg *.jpg *.pdf *.slddrw *.sldprt *.sldasm *.STEP *.x_t *.IGS *.DXF *.STP *.rpt *.err *.txt') do (
    set "files=%%G"
    set "folders=!files:~0,11!"
    if not exist "!folders!" md "!folders!"
    Move "%%G" "!folders!"
)
Pause

PopD
```

Comment: General notes: (1) Why do you believe that you need `endlocal` and two `setlocal` statements?  It’s typical just to do a `setlocal` at the beginning and leave it at that.  (2) I’m not sure it makes sense to do ``endlocal`` in a loop.  (3) Your last statement (third-to-last line) has an unmatched quote.  (4) It’s a good idea to comment your code.  Doing so will force you to take another look at the code and maybe find the problem yourself.  But, even if that doesn’t happen, it’s helpful to the people who will be reading your code. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (5) Please try to explain more clearly what you want to happen and what is happening that’s different.  In particular, I don’t understand what you mean by “part”. … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

It makes much more sense to :

- iterate present folders (sorted reverse to have longer names first)
- and use the names as a prefix to move files with an attached wildcard `*.*`

This batch

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\04\22\SU_1428072.cmd
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "basedir=X:\Path\to\files-n-folders"

PushD "%baseDir%" || (echo couldn't locate baseDir & pause & exit /B 1)

:: iterate all dirs and move files with same prefix to dir
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /AD ^| sort /R') do Move "%%a*.*" "%%a"

:: there shouldn't be any files left with matching dir
 for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D') do (
    set "file=%%a"
    set "folder=!file:~0,11!"
    if not exist "!folder!" md "!folder!"
    Move "%%a" "!folder!"
)

PopD
```

converts this initial tree

```
> tree /F
│   X-01234-567.dwg
│   X-01234-567.pdf
│   X-09902-024 (rev B).dwg
│   X-09902-024 (rev B).pdf
│   X-09902-024 Adapter, 0.38 NPT to Engine Block.dwg
│   X-09902-024 Adapter, 0.38 NPT to Engine Block.jpg
│   X-09902-024 Adapter, 0.38 NPT to Engine Block.pdf
│   X-09902-024 Adapter, 0.38 NPT to Engine Block.sldasm
│   X-09902-024 Adapter, 0.38 NPT to Engine Block.slddrw
│   X-09902-024 Adapter, 0.38 NPT to Engine Block.sldprt
│   X-09902-024 Rev A Adapter, 0.38 NPT to Engine Block.dwg
│   X-09902-024 Rev A Adapter, 0.38 NPT to Engine Block.pdf
│
├───X-01234-567
└───X-09902-024 Adapter, 0.38 NPT
```

into this result

```
> tree /f
├───X-01234-567
│       X-01234-567.dwg
│       X-01234-567.pdf
│
├───X-09902-024
│       X-09902-024 (rev B).dwg
│       X-09902-024 (rev B).pdf
│       X-09902-024 Rev A Adapter, 0.38 NPT to Engine Block.dwg
│       X-09902-024 Rev A Adapter, 0.38 NPT to Engine Block.pdf
│
└───X-09902-024 Adapter, 0.38 NPT
        X-09902-024 Adapter, 0.38 NPT to Engine Block.dwg
        X-09902-024 Adapter, 0.38 NPT to Engine Block.jpg
        X-09902-024 Adapter, 0.38 NPT to Engine Block.pdf
        X-09902-024 Adapter, 0.38 NPT to Engine Block.sldasm
        X-09902-024 Adapter, 0.38 NPT to Engine Block.slddrw
        X-09902-024 Adapter, 0.38 NPT to Engine Block.sldprt
```

Comment: First off, I apologize for the incredibly long time to respond. This is a side project at work, and I got hammered with other work. This script works for the most part, but it's not quite what I'm going for. If I already had a folder named "X-09902-024 Adapter, 0.38 NPT" I would want everything from both "X-09902-024" folders to be in that one folder, with the name unchanged. Some of our part numbers have the extra information to help the user identify what the part is used for, but it doesn't all have it yet. X-09902-024 is the part number though, so all of those files are the same part.